# WPF DataGrid bind to cell of same row

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a Data Grid with 3 columns, the first is a ComboBox that is populated identicly for all cells. Now, the second column, which is also a ComboBox , each cell needs to be populated by a List in the selected item of the first column in the same row. How do I bind a column cell to another column cell in the same row? The third column, a text column, should be filled with a property in the selected item in the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm assuming your DataRow object contains the SelectedIndex or SelectedItem of whatever is selected in Column1, so you can base your Column2 DataSource off that value.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public SomeClass Column1SelectedItem {get; set;}
}

<ComboBox x:Name="Column2" DataSource="{Binding Column1SelectedItem.Items}" />
```

Comment: No, sorry, it doesn't contain the selected item or index. That is because of a many to many relation. Anyway, I need something that doesn't rely on the data model. Also I work in a place that has the most annoying tendency to reject the simple soloutin of behind code and likes me to break my head against the wall trying to come up with stuff in pure xaml.

Comment: I may have found the way, but I'm not sure on how to write it in the xaml syntax... How do I write a binding that has a relative source inside another relative source? I intend to go up the tree to the DataGridCellsPanel and then down the tree to a ComboBox, using type as my search guide and also adding path to select the right cell child of the DataGridCellsPanel.

Comment: So dar what I have is this: {Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCellsPanel, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Children[0]} But this only gets me the right cell. If I try to get that cell's content I get a ContentPresenter, and the ConetentPresenter's Content is the row item which doesn't help me.

Comment: Okay! I found a way that works! It's not perfect because it takes a binding from each element and using the Tag property as kind of middle man, I use the relative source to to find the first column's comboxBox's cell and place the selected item in it's tag and since I can already reach that cell from the second column it easy eanough to set the binding to the same tag.